# Can a normal PASSENGER pilot a plane with no training?

Tags: landing, emergency

This is an extreme question, but I am daring it because I want to.

Situation :

- All pilots, officers, die.
- just say no crews can pilot a plane
- no former pilot in the passenger

Only option is for a normal passenger to pilot a plane. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any help, and no prior introduction, it is highly unlikely in a transport or biz jet.  Too much complexity, too much a priori knowledge needed, and too many flight configuration changes to land the plane.  Just an opinion.

There have been lots of attempts to take the uninitiated and have them pilot a simulator to a landing. The outcomes are not favorable, unless there is some previous experience or there is very very active coaching. Every now and then, someone writes a paper or magazine article on this. There have been no large scale studies where more than a handful of lay people have been "tested."

So bottom line, somewhat informed opinion, no it is not likely that the uninitiated would be able to fly to a selected destination and land a plane that is in the transport or bizjet class.